# Pass cell array as function argument in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of 100 256x256 images. How can I pass them as function argument? I tried

```
function[d] = thresh(c{k})
```

but it gives an error when called using

```
x = thresh(c);
```

I also tried

```
function [ ] = thresh(c)
```

which didn't work either.

Comment: have you read the documentation on functions in matlab? your syntax looks all wrong. RTFM and post more context code if you still are stuck

Comment: Could you please specify the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the cell as an argument and then find the elements back:

```
function thresh(c)

for i=1:numel(c)
    % your code here
    % c{i} refers to image i
end
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

Your function syntax looks wrong to me.

If, for example you want apply another function to each image of the cell array you should do something like that.

```
num_images = 100;

function [output] = thresh(c)

for i = 1:num_images
modifiedImage = modifyImage(c{k})
end
```

Let us know what you want to do with the image and which is your error if you still have one.

Comment: No it is not working.. My code is too much lengthy and i want to break it in small functions. where this function needs to call again and again.. i am reading images from directory and then passing to this function for segmentation and want to return back to the main body. and don't want to overwrite my images..  want to save result of each segmentation.