# Matlab / M - pass a cell array into a function as input

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells, cell-array

I have a very basic Matlab/M function to take the first cell of a cell array, then return the cell removed and the rest of the cell array minus the first cell, like taking the first item out of a queue. Matlab seems to have a fit about the type of the input being a cell array. Is it possible to pass cell arrays into functions?

I saved the function with a filename the same as the function, i.e. `fpop.m`, and I double-checked my input, but I'm getting the error: `Undefined function 'fpop' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`

This is my simple function code:

```
function [cell, outqueue] = fpop(queue)
% DELETE FIRST ELEMENT ONLY, RETURN REMAINDER
%Queue

outqueue = {};
cell = {};
if size(queue,2) < 1
    %do nothing
elseif size(queue,2) < 2
    cell = queue{1};
else
    cell = queue{1};
    for i = 2:size(queue,2)
        outqueue{i-1} = queue{i};
    end
end
```

The code I used to call the function and the cell array input:

```
myqueue = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}};
[outpair, myarray] = fpop(myqueue);
```

I tested all the statements outside of the function, so I know everything is working. I just seem to have something wrong with the function call -- or perhaps passing a cell array into a function is just not possible.

I did some checking online, and the info I found says that I need to reference the specific part of the cell array I want to pass, essentially passing in not the cell array but the variable(s)/object(s) inside the cell. I don't want to pass in the objects individually though -- I want to pass in the entire array and then do work on the cell array. Is this possible?

Also, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262842/pass-cell-array-as-function-argument-in-matlab) here on SO, but none of the answers seemed to address the issue and since I don't know all the factors of the original issue, it seemed better to start a new question.

Comment: The error you get typically results from Matlab being unable to find the function file. Try to change Matlab's working directory to the one where your function file `fpop.m` is located and see if the call function works then.

Comment: Are you **sure** `fpop` is in the same directory as your Working Directory?  What does `which fpop` give you?  If it returns "`'fpop' not found`", that means MATLAB can't find the file in its search path.  Change your Working Directory to be where the file is located.  Consult the duplicate for more details.

Comment: Also don't name a variable `cell`

Comment: And by the way, it's poor practice to use the name `cell` for any variables you declare, since that is already a builtin name for Matlab's `cell` data type.

Comment: @Suever Ah, alright. Is `cell` a reserved keyword?

Comment: @AliumBritt Yes, `cell` is to **create blank cell arrays**: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html.  What you are doing is certainly another method to create cell arrays, but these are all initialized with contents.  Doing `cell(M,N)` would create a 2D cell array of size `M x N`.  It's standard MATLAB practice to not overshadow function names with variables.

Comment: Ok, that did the trick! I moved the `fpop.m` file to the working directory and now everything seems to work fine. I can't mark a comment as an answer though, so @mikkola and @rayryeng since you both gave me the same answer, can you put an answer at the bottom and I'll mark it as completed? Or I can just write the answer myself if you prefer.

Comment: The linked duplicate question seems to provide an equivalent answer so no need to post it here I suppose.

Comment: @AliumBritt You can go ahead and write your own answer.  This kind of answer does not merit earning reputation points for as it is a well known problem with many good precedents for answers, such as the duplicate I have marked.  Therefore, there is little point in us writing one.